# SQL Server sum and subtract prevent null results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using this code:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(TrnQty) AS Total 
     FROM InventoryTrans 
     WHERE InventoryItemID = (select MAX(InventoryItemID) 
                              from inventorymaster) 
       AND CustomerID = '0') - 
    (SELECT SUM(TrnQty) AS Total 
     FROM InventoryTrans 
     WHERE InventoryItemID = (select MAX(InventoryItemID) 
                              from InventoryMaster) 
       AND CustomerID > '0'
)
```

If the result of one them is NULL i take totally result NULL. How can I `SUM` if one of them is Null? Should I use `CASE` or something?

Comment: So where inventoryitemid isnotnull?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(TrnQty), 0) ...
```

Comment: THIS is the correct way to achieve what the person posting was looking for.  While the other approaches suggested may work, they are cumbersome, especially when Microsoft builds in functions to do what all of the other hand-written code does.  Thank you for an elegant and simple answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a correct way to do it

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN customerid = '0' THEN trnqty 
             ELSE 0 
           END) - Sum(CASE 
                        WHEN customerid > '0' THEN trnqty 
                        ELSE 0 
                      END) AS Total 
FROM   inventorytrans 
WHERE  inventoryitemid = (SELECT Max (inventoryitemid) 
                          FROM   inventorymaster)
```

EDIT:

I [@GordonLinoff] am providing a slightly simpler version of this answer. The use of conditional aggregation is correct, but there is a simpler way of writing it:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN it.customerid = '0' THEN it.trnqty 
                WHEN it.customerid > '0' THEN  - it.trnqty 
                ELSE 0
           END) as Total
FROM inventorytrans it
WHERE it.inventoryitemid = (SELECT Max(im.inventoryitemid) 
                            FROM inventorymaster im
                           )
```

Comment: Gordan, Yeah that is more simplified

Comment: The answer using 'COALESCE' is far simpler and takes advantage of built-in SQL Server functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
   SELECT ISNULL(SUM(TrnQty),0)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your existing inner select statements in an ISNULL function. It is simple to implement and your intent is clear, if your SELECT returns a null value, use 0.

```
SELECT 
IsNull(
(
   SELECT SUM(TrnQty) AS Total 
   FROM InventoryTrans 
   WHERE InventoryItemID = 
   (
      select MAX (InventoryItemID) from inventorymaster
   ) 
   and CustomerID='0'
),0) - 
IsNull(
(
   SELECT SUM(TrnQty) AS Total 
   FROM InventoryTrans 
   WHERE InventoryItemID = 
   (
      select MAX (InventoryItemID) from InventoryMaster
   ) 
   and CustomerID > '0'
),0)
```

Is this a great example of SQL, not really, but you can see how wrapping the select statements with IsNull is a minor change to your existing query to give you the results you need.

This query could be re-written into a single set based operation, here's my go at it:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE customerid WHEN '0' THEN -TrnQty ELSE TrnQty END) AS Total 
FROM InventoryTrans 
WHERE InventoryItemID = 
(
   select MAX (InventoryItemID) from inventorymaster
)
```

It is not necessary in this new query to check for null, (either with IsNull or Coalesce) unless you need to ensure that the end result is not null, this query will only return null if ALL of the TrnQty fields are also null. If that is a problem for you logic, wrap the SUM function in an IsNull function as well.